# how to run shell commands from apache (through php )

Tags: apache-2.2, redhat, shell-scripting

I'm using redhat 6 
 I have the following shell commands that I need to run from the webserver (apache -> through php )  that basically move & overwrite a file , kill a process and starts another . Obviously for some reasons all the operations are denied so I'm wondering if there is any way to execute them (e.g. what permission and how should I give to apache )

```
echo  shell_exec('mv -f /etc/resolv.test /etc/resolv.conf');
echo  shell_exec('killall horas');
echo  shell_exec('/xg/eng/sbin/startme &> /dev/null &');
```

the error log is 
mv: cannot move `/etc/resolv.test' to`/etc/resolv.conf': Permission denied
horas(2105): Operation not permitted
horas: no process killed

Comment: Do your clients know you are doing this? If I were them, I'd run away as fast as possible.

Comment: @Deer what clients ? I'm running my own stuff .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> well I'm aware that apache runs under apache but I think the question is how to give more permissions to apache so it can execute all these commands

the typical way to do this is to grant apache `sudo` access with NOPASSWD. you will want to be overly cautious with this because this can be exceedingly dangerous if misconfigured. something like

```
apache    ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: killall horas
```

might work. you might also want to write the whole thing up as a "wrapper" script and then only grant apache sudo access to that one script. ([another reply](https://serverfault.com/a/470473/6134) recommends this as well.)

remember, you are granting apache both execution **AND** privilege escalation. this is potentially a root-level remote exploit. test your scripts before deploying it and make sure you investigate securing access to the page with basic authentication and/or IP allows. you may also be better served investigating alternate solutions. does apache really need to manage your resolv.conf? could a cronjob perform the `killall`?

Comment: +1 for answering the question, but also stating strongly that it's a terrible idea. Unfortunately, it's hard to stop people doing stupid things, but let's hope.

Answer (score 1):

Apache processes runs normally as a special user ('apache' normally in Redhat). Find that out first. Then, you need to check that that user is allowed to perform that operation (files/dirs  permissions).

It's very dangerous to let the user that runs the web server have big privileges to execute sensitive scripts that only root should perform. I don't know exactly your scenario, but judging from the snippet, I'd go with something more cautios as having a frequently running (once per minute) cron script (for root user perhaps) that just checks for the existence of some file, that is generated by the php script - if the file is present, it executes the task and removes the file.

Comment: well I'm aware that apache runs under apache but I think the question is how to give more permissions to apache so it can execute all these commands .

Comment: @user1963938 What this answer is telling you is giving those permissions to apache is a *bad idea*. It pretty much defies the point of running apache as a limited user (or rather, stops that being the case).

Comment: all the requests are made by my API / application so the "user" is not dangerous.

Comment: see also here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9873970/277304

Answer (score 0):

I usually do one of the following:

- Make php update a database and have a minutely cronjob running as the correct user that checks that database. This will introduce a delay, but is safest
- Wrap all these commands in a shellscript and make apache run `sudo -u correctuser_here /path/to/script` and of course add permissions for this to /etc/sudoers: `www-data ALL=correctuser /path/to/script`
- And my favourite: use queueing software (I'm partial to beanstalk as it's simple): Make php add an item to a queue and have a daemon in the background constantly retrieve and process items.

In your usecase option 2 sounds like the right thing to do.